# How to work transactionally with spring-integration-smb

Tags: transactions, spring-integration

I am new to the Spring Integration project. I am trying to process remote files (from an SMB2 share) transactionally with the `spring-integration-smb` project. With the help of this [blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-integration-transaction) I was able to process files transactionally (with Spring's `PseudoTransactionManager`) on the **local** filesystem. Now I've tried to adjust the sample to process files on a remote share (SMB), but I haven't found a solution to make to processing transactional. Have you any idea how I can implement such a transactional processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can use similar approach with a `PseudoTransactionManager` and `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` combination to track your transaction statuses.

For rollback-kinda operations you can use an `SmbRemoteFileTemplate` to call its `rename()`, `remove()` etc. operations. The failed message contains for you all necessary info in the headers:

```
messageBuilder.setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_HOST_PORT, uri.getHost() + ':' + uri.getPort())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY, uri.getPath())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE, uri.getFragment());
```